# Draw a ring around a circle in Progress Tracker

Tags: css, flexbox

How can I draw a ring around the circle in this progress tracker like on the image [ring around circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQkze.png?) 
The progress tracker is based on http://nigelotoole.github.io/progress-tracker/

Here is the example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JewMeM

The approach was with:

```
.progress-step.is-active .progress-marker {
  background-color: #2196F3;
  border: 2px solid #0e38b1;
}
```

There must be an empty/white space between the ring and the circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some pseudo elements.

Try this

```
.progress-step.is-active .progress-marker::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #0e38b1;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```css
.progress-tracker {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.progress-step {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1 1 0%;
          flex: 1 1 0%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 28px;
}

.progress-step:last-child {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
      -ms-flex-positive: 0;
          flex-grow: 0;
}

.progress-step:not(:last-child)::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -10;
  top: 6px;
  bottom: 12px;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.progress-step.is-active .progress-title {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.progress-step > a {
  display: block;
}

.progress-marker {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: background-color, border-color;
  transition: background-color, border-color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
          transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.progress-text {
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 9.3333333333px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.progress-title {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.progress-step .progress-marker {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0e38b1;
}

.progress-step::after {
  background-color: #0e38b1;
}

.progress-step .progress-text, .progress-step .progress-step > a .progress-text {
  color: #333333;
}

.progress-step.is-active .progress-marker {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.progress-step.is-complete .progress-marker {
  background-color: #1976D2;
}

.progress-step.is-complete::after {
  background-color: #868686;
}

.progress-step:hover .progress-marker {
  background-color: #56ADF5;
}

.progress-tracker--center .progress-step {
  text-align: center;
}

.progress-tracker--center .progress-step:last-child {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex-positive: 1;
          flex-grow: 1;
}

.progress-tracker--center .progress-step::after {
  right: -50%;
}

.progress-tracker--center .progress-marker {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.progress-tracker--right .progress-step {
  text-align: right;
}

.progress-tracker--right .progress-step:last-child {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex-positive: 1;
          flex-grow: 1;
}

.progress-tracker--right .progress-step::after {
  right: calc(-100% + 14px);
}

.progress-tracker--right .progress-marker {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.progress-tracker--border {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #868686;
  border-radius: 38px;
}

.progress-tracker--spaced .progress-step::after {
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.progress-tracker--word {
  padding-right: 38.6666666667px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.progress-tracker--word .progress-text {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.progress-tracker--word .progress-title {
  margin: 0;
}

.progress-tracker--word-center {
  padding-right: 38.6666666667px;
  padding-left: 38.6666666667px;
}

.progress-tracker--word-center .progress-text {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(calc(-50% + 14px));
          transform: translateX(calc(-50% + 14px));
}

.progress-tracker--word-right {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 38.6666666667px;
}

.progress-tracker--word-right .progress-text {
  padding-left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(calc(-100% + 28px));
          transform: translateX(calc(-100% + 28px));
}

.progress-tracker--text .progress-step:last-child {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex-positive: 1;
          flex-grow: 1;
}

.progress-tracker--text-top .progress-step::after {
  top: auto;
}

.progress-tracker--text-top .progress-text {
  height: 100%;
}

.progress-tracker--text-top .progress-marker {
  bottom: 28px;
}

.progress-tracker--text-inline .progress-step {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.progress-tracker--text-inline .progress-text {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 30;
  max-width: 70%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.progress-tracker--text-inline .progress-title {
  margin: 0;
}

.progress-tracker--square .progress-step {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.progress-tracker--square .progress-marker {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.33) translateY(-12px);
          transform: scaleX(0.33) translateY(-12px);
  border-radius: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 399px) {
  .progress-tracker-mobile {
    overflow-x: auto;
  }
  .progress-tracker-mobile .progress-tracker {
    min-width: 200%;
  }
}

.progress-tracker--vertical {
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
}

.progress-tracker--vertical .progress-step {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
          flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.progress-tracker--vertical .progress-step::after {
  right: auto;
  top: 14px;
  left: 12px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 100%;
}

.progress-tracker--vertical .progress-marker {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.progress-tracker--vertical .progress-text {
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-left: 42px;
}

.progress-tracker--vertical .progress-step:not(:last-child) .progress-text {
  padding-bottom: 42px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scale-up {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes scale-up {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  }
}

.anim-ripple .progress-marker::before, .anim-ripple-large .progress-marker::before, .anim-ripple-splash .progress-marker::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 30;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  visibility: hidden;
}

.anim-ripple :not(:active) .progress-marker::before, .anim-ripple-large :not(:active) .progress-marker::before, .anim-ripple-splash :not(:active) .progress-marker::before {
  -webkit-animation: scale-up 0.3s ease-out;
          animation: scale-up 0.3s ease-out;
}

.anim-ripple :focus .progress-marker::before, .anim-ripple-large :focus .progress-marker::before, .anim-ripple-splash :focus .progress-marker::before {
  visibility: visible;
}

.anim-ripple-large .progress-marker::before {
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
}

.anim-ripple-splash .progress-marker::before {
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}

.anim-ripple-double .progress-marker::before, .anim-ripple-double .progress-marker::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 30;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  visibility: hidden;
  background: none;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.anim-ripple-double :not(:active) .progress-marker::before, .anim-ripple-double :not(:active) .progress-marker::after {
  -webkit-animation: scale-up 0.3s ease-out 0s;
          animation: scale-up 0.3s ease-out 0s;
}

.anim-ripple-double :not(:active) .progress-marker::after {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.15s;
          animation-delay: 0.15s;
}

.anim-ripple-double :focus .progress-marker::before, .anim-ripple-double :focus .progress-marker::after {
  visibility: visible;
}

.anim-path .progress-step::after {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #0e38b1 50%, #868686 50%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0e38b1 50%, #868686 50%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: 0% 100%;
  -webkit-transition: background-position 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: background-position 0.3s ease-out;
}

.anim-path .progress-step.is-complete::after {
  background-position: -100% 100%;
}

.progress-step.is-active .progress-marker::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #0e38b1;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="progress-tracker progress-tracker--spaced">
  <li class="progress-step is-active">
    <span class="progress-marker"></span>
  </li>
  <li class="progress-step">
    <span class="progress-marker"></span>
  </li>
  <li class="progress-step">
    <span class="progress-marker"></span>
  </li>
  <li class="progress-step">
    <span class="progress-marker"></span>
  </li>
  <li class="progress-step">
    <span class="progress-marker"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Updated pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VVqQRw

Answer (score 0):

If you are not willing to change the HTML structure of your progress tracket, the easiest way would be with a box-shadow IMO, like so :

```
box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #FFF, 0 0 0 11px #000
```

The first box-shadow is going to be the color of the background (here set to 10px) and the second one is going to be the color of your border (here set to 11px so that it shows a 1px border). To change your border width or size simply adjust those two values.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you

```
<div class="cr1">
            <div class="cr2">

            </div>
    </div>
.cr1{
border: 10px solid #bababa;
    width: 232px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.cr2{
background: #bababa;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 56%;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 41px solid #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a box shadow will do the trick.

Change `.progress-step.is-active .progress-marker` to,

```
.progress-step.is-active .progress-marker {
   background-color: #2196F3;
   border: 3px solid #fff;
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #2196F3;
   margin-top: -1px
 }
```

Here's a working example: https://codepen.io/paddyfields/pen/GwPQPo

Answer (score 0):

You can add border with `:before` selector

```
.progress-step.is-active .progress-marker:before {
  content: "";
  border: 2px solid  #2196F3;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%
}
```

```css
.progress-tracker {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.progress-step {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1 1 0%;
          flex: 1 1 0%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 28px;
}

.progress-step:last-child {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
      -ms-flex-positive: 0;
          flex-grow: 0;
}

.progress-step:not(:last-child)::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -10;
  top: 6px;
  bottom: 12px;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.progress-step.is-active .progress-title {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.progress-step.is-active .progress-marker:before {
  content: "";
  border: 2px solid  #2196F3;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%
}

.progress-step > a {
  display: block;
}

.progress-marker {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: background-color, border-color;
  transition: background-color, border-color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
          transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.progress-text {
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 9.3333333333px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.progress-title {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.progress-step .progress-marker {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0e38b1;
}

.progress-step::after {
  background-color: #0e38b1;
}

.progress-step .progress-text, .progress-step .progress-step > a .progress-text {
  color: #333333;
}

.progress-step.is-active .progress-marker {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.progress-step.is-complete .progress-marker {
  background-color: #1976D2;
}

.progress-step.is-complete::after {
  background-color: #868686;
}

.progress-step:hover .progress-marker {
  background-color: #56ADF5;
}

.progress-tracker--center .progress-step {
  text-align: center;
}

.progress-tracker--center .progress-step:last-child {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex-positive: 1;
          flex-grow: 1;
}

.progress-tracker--center .progress-step::after {
  right: -50%;
}

.progress-tracker--center .progress-marker {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.progress-tracker--right .progress-step {
  text-align: right;
}

.progress-tracker--right .progress-step:last-child {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex-positive: 1;
          flex-grow: 1;
}

.progress-tracker--right .progress-step::after {
  right: calc(-100% + 14px);
}

.progress-tracker--right .progress-marker {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.progress-tracker--border {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #868686;
  border-radius: 38px;
}

.progress-tracker--spaced .progress-step::after {
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.progress-tracker--word {
  padding-right: 38.6666666667px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.progress-tracker--word .progress-text {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.progress-tracker--word .progress-title {
  margin: 0;
}

.progress-tracker--word-center {
  padding-right: 38.6666666667px;
  padding-left: 38.6666666667px;
}

.progress-tracker--word-center .progress-text {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(calc(-50% + 14px));
          transform: translateX(calc(-50% + 14px));
}

.progress-tracker--word-right {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 38.6666666667px;
}

.progress-tracker--word-right .progress-text {
  padding-left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(calc(-100% + 28px));
          transform: translateX(calc(-100% + 28px));
}

.progress-tracker--text .progress-step:last-child {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex-positive: 1;
          flex-grow: 1;
}

.progress-tracker--text-top .progress-step::after {
  top: auto;
}

.progress-tracker--text-top .progress-text {
  height: 100%;
}

.progress-tracker--text-top .progress-marker {
  bottom: 28px;
}

.progress-tracker--text-inline .progress-step {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.progress-tracker--text-inline .progress-text {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 30;
  max-width: 70%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.progress-tracker--text-inline .progress-title {
  margin: 0;
}

.progress-tracker--square .progress-step {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.progress-tracker--square .progress-marker {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.33) translateY(-12px);
          transform: scaleX(0.33) translateY(-12px);
  border-radius: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 399px) {
  .progress-tracker-mobile {
    overflow-x: auto;
  }
  .progress-tracker-mobile .progress-tracker {
    min-width: 200%;
  }
}

.progress-tracker--vertical {
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
}

.progress-tracker--vertical .progress-step {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
          flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.progress-tracker--vertical .progress-step::after {
  right: auto;
  top: 14px;
  left: 12px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 100%;
}

.progress-tracker--vertical .progress-marker {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.progress-tracker--vertical .progress-text {
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-left: 42px;
}

.progress-tracker--vertical .progress-step:not(:last-child) .progress-text {
  padding-bottom: 42px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scale-up {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes scale-up {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  }
}

.anim-ripple .progress-marker::before, .anim-ripple-large .progress-marker::before, .anim-ripple-splash .progress-marker::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 30;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  visibility: hidden;
}

.anim-ripple :not(:active) .progress-marker::before, .anim-ripple-large :not(:active) .progress-marker::before, .anim-ripple-splash :not(:active) .progress-marker::before {
  -webkit-animation: scale-up 0.3s ease-out;
          animation: scale-up 0.3s ease-out;
}

.anim-ripple :focus .progress-marker::before, .anim-ripple-large :focus .progress-marker::before, .anim-ripple-splash :focus .progress-marker::before {
  visibility: visible;
}

.anim-ripple-large .progress-marker::before {
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
}

.anim-ripple-splash .progress-marker::before {
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}

.anim-ripple-double .progress-marker::before, .anim-ripple-double .progress-marker::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 30;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  visibility: hidden;
  background: none;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.anim-ripple-double :not(:active) .progress-marker::before, .anim-ripple-double :not(:active) .progress-marker::after {
  -webkit-animation: scale-up 0.3s ease-out 0s;
          animation: scale-up 0.3s ease-out 0s;
}

.anim-ripple-double :not(:active) .progress-marker::after {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.15s;
          animation-delay: 0.15s;
}

.anim-ripple-double :focus .progress-marker::before, .anim-ripple-double :focus .progress-marker::after {
  visibility: visible;
}

.anim-path .progress-step::after {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #0e38b1 50%, #868686 50%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0e38b1 50%, #868686 50%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: 0% 100%;
  -webkit-transition: background-position 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: background-position 0.3s ease-out;
}

.anim-path .progress-step.is-complete::after {
  background-position: -100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="progress-tracker progress-tracker--spaced">
  <li class="progress-step is-active">
    <span class="progress-marker"></span>
  </li>
  <li class="progress-step">
    <span class="progress-marker"></span>
  </li>
  <li class="progress-step">
    <span class="progress-marker"></span>
  </li>
  <li class="progress-step">
    <span class="progress-marker"></span>
  </li>
  <li class="progress-step">
    <span class="progress-marker"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```